# Division and floating point in verilog

Tags: floating-point, verilog, division

I have 52 bit binary in Verilog (like `f`). I want to convert it to `1.f`.
What should I do?

```
re={1'b1,51'b0};
f=(a[51:0]/re)+1;
```

In my Verilog code I do something like that, but the output is `0000...0001`.

Comment: You should also show how you have declared `f`,`re`,`fa`,`fb`.

Comment: I want floating point number, fa and fb are reg(this code is in always block, re too. but where is f?@morgan

Comment: The question starts with "I have 52 bit binary in Verilog (like `f`)." The statement would be clearer if we actually could see what f was.

Comment: variables declared as `real` are floating point, but they are not synthesisable.  If you want an implementation that can be turned into hardware I would suggest you look for a floating point core, it is not a trivial task in verilog. http://opencores.org/project,fpu

Comment: I am sorry because of my unclear question. I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

The result remains "0000...0001" because you specify a integer division. If you want to do float division, you should declare the signals to be real. For example:

```
real a = 30.000;
real re = $bitstoreal({1'b1, 51'b0});
f = (a/re)+1;
```

However this is OK for simulation. If you want float division done in hardware, you'd better use float division IP core. At least both Xilinx and Altera provide this core for free. It is not wise to re-invent this complex logic on your own.